# Using "Remove" in LINQ with Entity Framework 6 causing compile error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

This method is not compiling and I don't seem to be able to find good fix.

The goals is to delete all rows from the "Period Table" called `tblPeriods` that have a `StartDate` greater than or equal to the `fromDate` variable being passed in:

```
public override bool BulkDeletePeriods(DateTime fromDate)
{
    var entities = GetEntities();

    var toDelete = entities.tblPeriods
                           .Where(x => x.StartDate >= fromDate);

    entities.tblPeriods.Remove(toDelete);

    return Convert.ToBoolean(entities.SaveChanges());
}
```

This the compile time error I get:

> Error CS1503
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'tblPeriod'

Comment: You probably forgot to add FirstOrDefault when fetching toDelete

Comment: Try `RemoveRange` instead. You have passed `IQueryable` instead of object.

Comment: Remove => A single row in a database. RemoveRange => multiple rows in a

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Remove` works that way. "Bulk" operations in general don't really work by default in EF, although I think you can get third-party libraries that have them.

The quick solution to your example is something like this:

```
var toDelete = 
   entities
   .tblPeriods
   .Where(x => x.StartDate >= fromDate)
   .ToList();

foreach (var item in toDelete)
   entities.tblPeriods.Remove(item);
```

Or with `RemoveRange`:

```
var toDelete = 
   entities
   .tblPeriods
   .Where(x => x.StartDate >= fromDate)
   .ToList();

entities.tblPeriods.RemoveRange(toDelete);
```

Note that `RemoveRange` is still not a "bulk" operation. It will individually delete each row by its key. If you actually wanted a `DELETE WHERE`, you would need some kind of third-party library, as mentioned. (Though bulk operations may be coming soon in EF Core if I recall.)